# Cauchy–Schwarz inequality properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ an inner product space

Let $ F = C $

Let $u,v \in V$

I have to show that:

if

$\|v+u\| =\|u\| + \|v\| $

then

$\exists c \in R$ $ c>0 $ such that  $u=cv$ or $u=0$ or $v=0$

How come $c$ as to be a real number ?

I tried it but in all places they keep saying it is obvious

Thanks in advanced !!

Comment: $\Rightarrow$ direction: if $u=cv$, then $||u+v|| = ||cv+v|| = ||(c+1)v|| = (c+1)||v|| = c||v||+||v|| = ||u||+||v||$.

Comment: Consider $v = i\cdot u$. What is $\lVert v\rVert$, and what is $\lVert u + v\rVert$? Geometrically, if you view the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $V$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, how are $u$ and $i\cdot u$ situated?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you !! but u do the other direction ?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is clearly satisfied in the $u=v=0$ case. We show the case $u=cv$, with $c>0$ (and $u,v\neq 0$)

The relation

$$\|u+v\|=\|u\|+\|v\|~~(*)$$

implies

$$\|u\|\|v\|=\operatorname{Re}(\langle u,v\rangle)>0.~~(**)$$

To prove $(**)$, just consider

$$\langle u+v,u+v\rangle=\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2\operatorname{Re}(\langle u,v\rangle), $$

and

$$\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+2\|u\|\|v\|,$$

which is a consequence of $(*)$.

We want to prove that there exists a $c>0$ s.t. $u=cv$. To find such $c$
we show that the vector $u-cv$ is the zero vector (with $c>0$!), which is equivalent to state that

$$\langle u-cv,u-cv \rangle=\|u-cv\|^2=0,~~(***) $$

by definition of inner product/norm on $V$. 
Eq. $(***)$ is equivalent to the degree $2$ equation in the variable $c$

$$c^2\|v\|^2-2c\operatorname{Re}(\langle u,v \rangle)+\|u\|^2=0, $$

which has positive coincident solutions (thanks to $(**)$)

$$c_1=c_2:=c= \frac{\operatorname{Re}(\langle u,v \rangle)}{\|v\|^2}=(\text{I use $(**)$})=\frac{\|u\|}{\|v\|}.$$

In summary, the non negative real number $c=\frac{\|u\|}{\|v\|}$ gives the statement.

- ADD-ON: Geometric intuition (for reals)

Let us consider $V=\mathbb R^2$ with the scalar product

$$\langle u,v \rangle:=\|u\|\|v\|\cos(\theta),$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors $u$ and $v$. Then $(*)$ implies
$\langle u,v \rangle=\|u\|\|v\|$ which is satisfied
iff $\cos(\theta)=1$, i.e. $\theta=0$. In other words,  the vectors $u$ and $v$ are collinear. The factor $c>0$ s.t. $u=cv$ is clearly given by $c=\frac{\|u\|}{\|v\|}$. Heuristically, if $c>1$, then we are "stretching" $v$ in order to compare it to $u$. If $c<1$, then $v$ is "compressed", instead. If $c=1$, then there is no operation to perform on $v$.